# Hard-coded URL is invalid because of HTML encoding

Tags: javascript

Below download url is not working because of the presence of amp; in the url

```
window.open('dev.test.com/download?parent_id=223344553268&amp;sid=28&amp;child=2454367720');
```

How is it possible to handle the above issue ?

Comment: Change `&amp;` to `&`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regular expression to replace `&amp;` with &

```
$url =~ s/amp;//gis;
```

This is the perl syntax. You can check for regex in Javascript but the pattern would remain same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'http://dev.test.com/download?parent_id=223344553268&amp;sid=28&amp;child=2454367720';

url.replace(/\&amp;/g,'&'));

window.open(url);
```